# Iterate over a list using an iterator and compare consecutive elements

Tags: java, list, loops, iterator

I want to compare each element in a single list and the code directly below provides me my solution:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
        // compare 
    }
}
```

It compares elements index wise, for instance comparing four elements:

```
0 to 1
0 to 2
0 to 3
1 to 2
1 to 3
2 to 3
```

I want to achieve the same as above using an iterator. My implementation using an iterator:

```
int i = 0;
for (Iterator<Tuple> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Tuple tB = null;
    Tuple tA = it.next();

    for(int j = 0; j == i; j++) {
        try {
            tB = it.next();

            if(tA.Username.equals(tB.Username) && .....) {
                System.out.println("Match");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not Matched");
            }
            i++;
        } catch(NoSuchElementException exc) {
            throw exc;
        }   
    }
}
```

`Tuple` is a class with some string properties.

This code only compares the first element with the others and throws `NoSuchElementException`, but I want to move from inner for-loop to the outer for-loop to keep traversing. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need an inner iterator and an outer iterator.

Comment: What's wrong with direct access? Your code works already.

Comment: @Bohemian I am writing java udf for apache-pig and for testing purposes I tried it on plain java the direct access here works well but I used apache pig's Tuple class and made list out of it.I was not able to access the properties with i.get(arg) method ..which I was able to achieve in plain java.Tuple class implements Iterator interface so I tried to test the same with java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you get the Exception because of your it.next() within the inner for loop. You need a second Iterator.

```
 for (Iterator<Tuple> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) 
{
       Tuple tA = it.next();
       List<Tuple> tmpList = new ArrayList<Tuple>(list);
       tmpList.remove(tA);
  for( Iterator<Tuple> it2 = tmpList.iterator(); it2.hasNext();)     {
        try{
            Tuple tB=it2.next();

            if(tA.Username.equals(tB.Username) && .....)
            {
                System.out.println("Match");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Not Matched");
            }
            i++;
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException exc)
        {
            throw exc;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: It returns two new Iteratos

Comment: code compares each object to the other.It also compares with itself...How to prevent that same indexed objects are not compared with each other?I am trying for the same

Comment: You could use a new list and remove the element from it. Edited in the post.

Comment: here item1 is compared to item2 and then item2 is again compared to item2...So how can we stop this comparision

Answer (score 1):

To compliment [shsvd98 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38790524/1241334), you can use a `ListIterator` instead of an `Iterator`. `ListIterator` extends `Iterator` and provides more functionality.

For instance the following code does exactly what your first code block does. It also doesn't compare an element with itself and there's no need to create another `List` after each outer for-loop iteration.

```
Tuple tA = null;
Tuple tB = null;

for (ListIterator<Tuple> one = list.listIterator(); one.hasNext();) {
    // set 'tA' here, not in the nested for loop
    tA = one.next();

    // initialize 'two' with the next index of 'one'
    for(ListIterator<Tuple> two = list.listIterator(one.nextIndex()); two.hasNext();) {
        // set 'tB' here
        tB = two.next();

        // debug line used in output below this code block
        // System.out.print("tA:" + tA + " to tB:" + tB + " ");

        try {
            if(tA.username.equals(tB.username)) {
                System.out.println("Match");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not Matched");
            }
        } catch(NoSuchElementException exc) {
            throw exc;
        }  

    }
}
```

I ran the above code, switching out `Tuple` with `String`.

```
Populated ArrayList with ["a", "b", "c", "b"]

Output:
tA:a to tB:b Not Matched
tA:a to tB:c Not Matched
tA:a to tB:b Not Matched
tA:b to tB:c Not Matched
tA:b to tB:b Match
tA:c to tB:b Not Matched
```

If your curious about the benefits of using `ListIterator` over `Iterator`, then the [`ListIterator` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) provides more insight.

Comment: I need to iterate over https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/api/org/apache/pig/data/DataBag.html which implements Iterable so can't use ListIterator..Is there a way ?    It threw class cast exception when I tried to convert databag to list..